# How to make the following code return to a bash variable?

Tags: bash, grep, ping

So I'm trying to execute this:

```
internet=ping -c 3 google.com | grep -cim1 64;
```

which would return 1 if the computer is connected to the internet and 0 if it is not.
But clearly this does not assign the value to the variable, instead it just echoes it out. How can I assign the value?
Also, is there a more intelligent way to check from a bash script if a computer is connected to the internet?

And I would like to stick with ping, and not wget or whatever.

Comment: This code shouldn't do anything except complain that the `-c` command cannot be found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$(...)` is used to substitute the output of a command:

```
internet=$(ping -c 3 google.com 2>/dev/null | grep -cim1 64)
```

Comment: You should remove error form the ping if DNS is down, or not working. If not you would get error message and 0 in the variable. `internet=$(ping -c 3 google.comm 2> /dev/null | grep -cim1 64)`